# How to print my posts and posts of my friends?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, associations

I have 2 models, **user** and **friendship**, here's how they looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :friendships, :conditions => { :confirmed => true }
  has_many :friend_requests, :class_name => 'Friendship', :conditions => { :confirmed => false }
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :friends_friendships, :through => :friends, :source => :friendships
  has_many :friends_of_friends, :through => :friends_friendships, :source => :friend
  has_many :friends_listings, :through => :friends, :source => :listings
  has_many :friends_posts, :through => :friends, :source => :posts
  ...
end
```

and

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
  attr_accessible :friend_id
  ...
end
```

and here's how I fetch posts of currently logged in user and posts of his/her friends:

```
  @my_posts = current_user.posts.includes(:user)
  @friends_posts = current_user.friends_posts.includes(:user)
```

This is working well, but how can I load my posts + posts of my friends into one variable and display them as on Facebook? In other words, how can I merge those 2 queries into only one?

Thanks

Comment: I wrote an SQL to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

```
ids = current_user.friends.pluck(:id) << current_user.id
posts = Post.where(user_id: ids)
```

return

```
SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 6)
```

then in view:

```
posts.each do |post|
  ....
end
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your effort, I am trying this but cannot get over this error message: `SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT id FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = 2 AND "friendships"."confirmed" = 't'` - what's wrong?

Comment: `current_user.friends` returns you an array of users who are friends with current, right? it should be as you have `user has many friends` relation.

Comment: you can try it this way `ids = current_user.friends.map{|f| f.id} << current_user.id`, it will return you an array of ids too including your own, see if it works. May be pluck method didn't worked well for you.